# interpret data from universal gcode sender on raspberry pi

Tags: serial

I've finally finished everything on my home-built cnc-machine to the point where i can start making the software. At first i was planning to make a program on my raspberry pi (which controls the machine directly) that reads the gcode and outputs it to the stepper drivers, but i came across the popular "universal gcode sender" while i was doing some research. it seems way more elegant to use this program instead of trying to dissect the gcode myself.

After some time on google i coulnd't seem to find any examples of people trying this, and the only examples i could find are examples where people use the grbl shield on an arduino, where the arduino is recieving and the raspberry pi is sending the gcode. What i am trying to achieve is that my laptop/pc is sending and the raspberry pi is recieving. my question: because there's no examples to be found on google, is it possible to interpret gcode, sent by the universal gcode sender, on a raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but it's probably a bad idea.

The reason that Raspberry Pis aren't more prevalent as CNC controllers is that they're full Linux PCs. The operating system's doing many different things, and doesn't necessarily do all of them in a rigidly timed fashion.

Arduinos, on the other hand, *are* widely used as CNC controllers, because it's much easier to get them to spit out precisely timed signals to your axis motors.

I've got a Shapeoko gathering dust in my basement, and I can well imagine the truly horrific mayhem that would ensue if the controller decided to run a background daemon for a minute or two and slowed the spindle by a few percent.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi is a general purpose computer which can run several different operating system.

The most popular is Raspbian which is a Debian based distribution of Linux.

Yes, you can write a program to interpret G-code.

The repository has several programs which may be helpful in your task.

apt-cache search gcode

```
gpx - Gcode to x3g conversion post processor
pcb2gcode - command-line tool for engraving PCBs using CNCs
repsnapper - STL to GCode Converter and print software for RepRap machines
yagv - yet another G-code viewer
```

Comment: I took a look through the packages available through `apt-cache search gcode`. None of them appear to send gcode to motors, which I think is what the question's looking for. They're for generating gcode from various parameters, rather than running the mill.

Comment: @goobering Depends on the question you want to answer.  I was addressing "is it possible to interpret gcode, sent by the universal gcode sender, on a raspberry pi?".